# Vue - Prevent some table cells from firing my table row's event

Tags: vue.js, events

My row is as such

```
<tr @click="fireParentEvent">
  <td>Child 1</td>
  <td>Child 2</td>
  <td>Child 3</td>
</tr>
```

fireParentEvent changes the background color

Child 1 and Child 2 have their own actions and I don't want them to trigger the parent event when I click on them. Child 3 (and any additional td) should fire the parent event.

How would I go about doing that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you may use vue's `@click.stop` directive. e.g.

```
<script setup>
const fireParentEvent = () => console.log("parent");
const fireChildEvent = () => console.log("child");
</script>

<template>
  <tr @click="fireParentEvent" class="text-white">
    <td>Child 1</td>
    <td @click.stop="fireChildEvent">Child 2</td>
    <td>Child 3</td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

It would stop when `fireChildEvent` is triggered and the `fireParentEvent` would not be triggered. If you want both of them to be triggered you may use use the simple `@click` directive on the child element.